# How to get value counts based on type of value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data related to a survery. For ease, imagine this survey is asking people which colors they prefer, but with each color having multiple shades, as in the table below

| Participant | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| John | Red1, Red2, Red3, Blue1 |
| Steve | Red1, Blue2, Blue3, Yellow1 |
| Robert | Red1 |

Here is some code representing this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Participant': ['John','Steve','Robert'], 'Answer':[ 'Red1, Red2, Red3, Blue1', 'Red1, Blue2, Blue3, Yellow1', 'Red1']})
```

I want to be able to get frequencies for how many people choose a color, regardless of whether they choose shade1 or shade2 or any combination thereof. For example, for blue, I would want to get a returned value of 2 for the above data, as both John and Steve chose at least one blue shade. For red, I would want 3 as three people chose at least 1 red shade. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In your case do `explode` then `groupby` with `nunique`

```
s = df.assign(Answer = df['Answer'].str.split(', ')).explode('Answer')
s = s.groupby(s.Answer.str[:-1])['Participant'].nunique()
Out[109]: 
Answer
Blue      2
Red       3
Yellow    1
Name: Participant, dtype: int64
```